# Where to store the name of a custom table?

Tags: plugin-development, wpdb, customization

I'm extending the `$wpdb` object with properties for my custom tables.

```
function setup_wpdb()
{
    global $wpdb;

    // Create properties for custom tables
    $wpdb->my_plugin_table1 = $wpdb->prefix.'my_plugin_table1';
    $wpdb->my_plugin_table2 = $wpdb->prefix.'my_plugin_table2';
}
```

Is this a good practice? I guess as long as the properties are prefixed with the plugin name, it should be fine. Defining a constant may work too. What do you prefer and why? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as...

1. You use `$wpdb->prefix` (or `$wpdb->base_prefix`) to prefix the table
2. Your table name is someplace public, and easily available for other plugins, themes and end users to use and extend

I would say either setting the table as a property on `$wpdb` or using a constant is fine. If you choose to use `$wpdb` be aware that another plugin (or theme or whatever) can just overwrite your property in the same way you set it.  For that reason, it's a bit more "safe" to use something like a constant.

Also, always carefully question whether or not you need to add a table.

I tend to use constants, but if I'm doing something like creating a `termmeta` table, then I would use a `$wpdb` property.